# How to make 'hg up' in intellij idea mercurial plugin?

Tags: mercurial, intellij-idea

I found that after I make pull from plugin, it doesn't make 'hg up' automatically, so I need to go to console and make 'hg up' there. Is there a way to do it from Intellij or am I missing something here?

Also where can I see hg log in intellij to know what it actually does, what commands it issues when I do various hg-related actions from intellij?

Answer (score 0):

**First approach**

For pulling changes from remote repository you can use "Update project" command from "VCS -> Update Project..." menu item. By default it has four options and all of them are enabled:

- pull
- update
- merge
- commit after merge without conflicts

So by default this command will pull changes, update to latest revision, merge heads and commit merge result if there was no conflict.

**Second approach**

You can pull changes with "VCS -> Mercurial -> Pull..." menu item and then update to specific revision, branch or tag with "VCS -> Mercurial -> Update to..." menu item.